# coloring points on scatterplots containing two plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I would like to color the points on scatterplot containing two plots. I tried with the following code.

```
> df
    x1  y1  x2  y2
1  3.6 6.7 5.8 8.9
2 12.7 9.2 8.6 9.0
3  5.8 8.9 7.9 8.7
4   NA  NA 9.0 4.5
5   NA  NA 6.0 9.0

 x1= df$x1
 x2=df$x2
 y1=df$y1
 y2=df$y2
d1 <- data.frame(x1, y1, x2, y2)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d1) + geom_point(aes(x = x1, y = y1)) + geom_point(aes(x = x2, y = y2))+ xlim(0,15) + ylim(0,15) + xlab("data1") + ylab("data2")  +
  scale_colour_manual(name = 'data', values = setNames(c('red','green')))
```

your help would be appreciated!

Comment: So you have one plot and values from two groups?

Comment: @Maju116 Yeah, you are right.

Comment: Create a group variable and add it to `ggplot` as `color`. see example below

Comment: `geom_point(aes(x = x1, y = y1, color = "red") + geom_point(aes(x = x2, y = y2, color = "green"))` ?

Comment: Why did you ask your question again? Why not combine your data to one long dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem seems to be to get your data in the right format for plotting (judging from your question from yesterday). Generally, ggplot works best if for each data-point, all necessary information (at least x and y, but in this case group for colour) is one row in your data.

So, we first split your data into df1 and df2:

```
df1 <- cbind(df[,1:2],'1')
df2 <- cbind(df[,3:4],'2')
```

Then we give them the same column names:

```
colnames(df1) <- colnames(df2) <- c("x","y","id")
```

And bind them together

```
df_long <- rbind(df1,df2)

head(df_long,4)
# > head(df_long,4)
# x   y id
# 1  3.6 6.7  1
# 2 12.7 9.2  1
# 3  5.8 8.9  1
# 4   NA  NA  1
```

Plotting is then trivial:

```
p <- ggplot(df_long, aes(x=x,y=y,group=id,color=id))+
  geom_point()
p
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Based on my data, I need 8 points in the plot. But only 7 points in your plot.

Comment: There are 8. But one is invisible, as it is exactly in the same location as the other one and thus gets overplotted (at x=5.8). You can remedy this by using jitter, or faceting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dffx1<-data.frame(x1=1:5,y1=1:5,x2=6:10,y2=6:10)
dffx<-rbind(as.matrix(dffx1[,1:2]),as.matrix(dffx1[,3:4]))
df<-as.data.frame(dffx)
df<-cbind(df,group=c(rep(1,nrow(dffx1)),rep(2,nrow(dffx1))))
ggplot(df,aes(x=x1,y=y1,color=group))+geom_point(size=5)+
scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "green"), labels= c("red", "green")
```

[image])

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have 4 variables x1 and y1, x2 and y2. I need to combine the two plots into one. I think you did only with 2 variables.

Comment: Ok, I'll change my answer

Comment: Why all the conversions from dataframe to matrix and back?